# Added new custom colors to $theme-colors map but related classes are not created for text and background colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

**Describe the issue**

I added custom colors to the $theme-colors map, btn-, link- colors are generated perfectly but text- and bg- colors are not generated.

my main.scss file is as follows.

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
//custom-API file
@import './abstract/api';
```

and code in _api.scss is as follows.

```
//custom-colors
$custom-theme-colors: (
"altdark": #314259,
'altsecondary' : #F579A0
);
$theme-colors : map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);
```

**operating system(s)?**
windows

**Wversion of Bootstrap?**
5.2.0-beta1

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 5.2? This is a [bug](https://github.com/understrap/understrap/pull/1640) in earlier versions

Comment: I'm using 5.3 and having the same issue.